# If my Mac is connected to ethernet and WiFi, which will it use?

Tags: network, wifi

As per title. I have ethernet issues at home and if I just turn WiFi on my MacMini, will this take over or will it default to ethernet unless I pull the cable out?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can select the preferred connection in System Preferences -> Network.
Then use the Gear-Icon and select "Set Service Order...".

Your system will then prioritize the connection at the first position.

Comment: Can you set it to use both simultaneously?

Comment: @Cullub That's a very relevant question, but also much more complicated than you may realize. The two interfaces may be connected to the same network or two different networks. And if it is the same network does it use the same IP for both? And what if it is two different networks but both networks use the same IP range? And do the two networks run the same IP version or different IP versions or is one or both running dual stack? How is IP and outgoing interface chosen? Do you expect it to use ECMP? And are you communicating between two MPTCP capable devices?

Comment: Oh, I get that it might not work (or at least improve anything) for a lot of cases; I was just wondering if there were cases where being connected to WiFi and Ethernet would be beneficial.

Comment: One reason to use both Ethernet and WiFi could be if you want to be conmected to 2 different networks at the same time

Comment: What is the default preference in macOS? Does it matter if one is connected (or disconnected) first? What if you have multiple USB ethernet adapters connected?

Comment: From a system user point of view, there is little difference between the various physical connections you use as long as they all speak tcp (ie wifi, ethernet, thunderbolt ethernet etc. end up being treated the same) the OS will route traffic to the appropriate network. As @KevinGrabher said, useful for 2 networks, like when you are in a datacenter and want to simultaniously access the local lan to connect to servers, and connect to a dongle via wifi to get internet